# How can I send multiple emails (around 100) with different email body using amazon ses in NodeJS?

Tags: amazon-ses, email-templates

I am trying to send emails to multiple users with email body like

```
dear {{username}},
/.
....
Your email is {{email}}
...
.
/
```

how can I do those any ideas, I saw the custom templates for amazon ses but I have 100+ users so how will it be done ?

Comment: your `{{email}}` will be picking the email address from the data file. If you don't have a data file and just looping though records, then it will need a variable to replace the text in the HTML that will be sent out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SES bulk templated emails.

1. Create a template for your emails.

```html
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");

const ses = new AWS.SES({
    accessKeyId: <<YOUR_ACCESS_KEY>>,
    secretAccessKey: <<YOUR_ACCESS_KEY>>,
    region: <<YOUR_ACCESS_KEY>>
  }); 

const params = {
  Template: {
    TemplateName: "MyTemplate",
    SubjectPart: "Test mail for {{username}}!",
    HtmlPart: "<p>Dear {{username}}</p>, <p>Your email is {{email}}.</p>"
  }
}

ses.createTemplate(params, (err, data) =>  {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

2. Once it is done you would see the **MyTemplate** under Email templates of SES console. We no longer needed template creating part of the code.
3. Now we can send the email using the following.

```html
const users = [{username:"max", email: "max@m.com"},{username: "mosh", email:"mosh@h.com"}] // sample array of users

let destinations = []

for (const user of users) {
    destinations.push({
       Destination: {
         ToAddresses: [user.email]
       },
        ReplacementTemplateData: JSON.stringify({
          username: user.username,  // This will provide the value for username in template
          email: user.email // This will provide the value for email in template
        })
     });
}           

const params = {
   Source: "sender@xyz.com", // sender email
   Template: "MyTemplate", // Template name we have created
   Destinations: destinations, 
   DefaultTemplateData: JSON.stringify({
      username: '', // default value for username
      email: '' // default value for email
   })
}

ses.sendBulkTemplatedEmail(params, (err, data) =>  {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

Make sure you have given the ses:createTemplate and ses:sendBulkTemplatedEmail permissions for the IAM user before running this.

For more info see [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/send-personalized-email-api.html).

Comment: That's what I want to avoid doing `for (const user of users) {`  having a for loop to send, that is what I am currently doing, I want to send the bulk emails without looping. @Kanchana

Comment: Sending bulk email part is not done by a loop. Loop is used to push data to the destinations array. @AdarshGoyal